# Adding a quote/note for contact info in outlook.

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I noticed that some contacts have personal quotes that shows up when hovering over their name in an email. I'm not sure how to add my own quote to my profile.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at are Skypes personal messages. Outlook will now automatically look through your Skype contacts and connect them to the E-Mail addresses.